# Cloudbees: Does Play server services hibernate when there is not request for long time?

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloudbees

This problem may not be very unusual but I didn't find any solution to it. So, I am posting it anyway. And I am new to cloud and web development, so the question may seem, I lack fundamental knowledge.

I have open a new app with play framework in cloudbees and aliased it with my custom domain. Everything else is just excellent. But, when I am not sending any request for a long time, and then when I am sending request, not only the request takes a long time, if I refresh this a page with message "ACTIVATING" shows and then if I hit refresh, I get my desired page.

[image: first page thats showing]

And then after I hit refresh after sometime, I get my desired page.
[image: After I hit refresh I get the desired page]

P.S. its just the template cloudbees provide by default, I haven't edited anything. And I am currently subscribed to their free plan. Details [here](http://www.cloudbees.com/platform/pricing/devcloud.cb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Cloudbees FAQ (Why are my applications in sleep/hibernation model?)](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/FAQ)

"Free applications running on the platform will be hibernated periodically so resources can be used by other applications (the timeout is currently 2 hours).  Applications in hibernate mode will automatically activate when the next request for the application is detected. Paid applications will not hibernate by default. Applications that have not been updated in some time (over 6 months) may be temporarily stopped (you can reactivate them)."